# Android canvas setMatrix(null) crashes (if preceded by a getMatrix)

Tags: android

In the lunar lander example, if I add the following two lines to the top of the doDraw method, the app crashes immediately with a NullPointerException:

```
Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
canvas.setMatrix( null );
```

Stack trace is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Matrix.preConcat(Matrix.java:233)
    at android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas.setMatrix(Surface.java:259)
    at com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView$LunarThread.doDraw(LunarView.java:617)
    at com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView$LunarThread.run(LunarView.java:360)
```

The canvas documentation for setMatrix states that `If the matrix parameter is null, then the current matrix is reset to identity`, so there's no reason this should crash.

Also, if I do **not** call getMatrix before calling setMatrix(null), then setMatrix(null) is **successful**.  So somehow it is the combination of the two calls that are causing a problem.

Whats going on here?!